# method tableView editActionsForrowAtIndexPath with objective-c selector conflicts with method from superclass

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In my app I have class defined as follows:

```
class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController {
```

and inside I wanted to add the functionality of swiping selected cells (taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32586617/3766930) answer)

But when I write there this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]? {
    let more = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "More") { action, index in
        print("more button tapped")
    }
    more.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()

    let favorite = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Favorite") { action, index in
        print("favorite button tapped")
    }
    favorite.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()

    let share = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Share") { action, index in
        print("share button tapped")
    }
    share.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

    return [share, favorite, more]
}
```

I'm getting error:

> Method 'tableView(*:editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:)' with Objective-C
>   selector 'tableView:editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:' conflicts with
>   method 'tableView(*:editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:)' from superclass
>   'UITableViewController' with the same Objective-C selector

I tried to add `override` but it didn't help - what causes this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: Does changing `-> [AnyObject]?` to `-> [UITableViewRowAction]?` help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The signature is slightly different: the return value should be `[UITableViewRowAction]?` not `[AnyObject]?`:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]?
```

You need the `override` as well.