# Is there a way of implementing editActionsForRowAtIndexPath only for a specific UITableViewCell in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm implementing a `UITableViewController` in my app and I want to add a possibility of sliding/swiping a cell on my tableview, exactly like in this answer: [Swipe-able Table View Cell in iOS 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32004557/swipe-able-table-view-cell-in-ios9-or-swift-guide-at-least/32586617#32586617) but with a difference that it works only for one specific cell, not all of them. So far I have:

```
class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController {



override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func tableView(tableView: (UITableView!), commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: (NSIndexPath!)) {

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    var deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Hello There!") {action in
        print("some action!!")
    }

    return [deleteAction]
}

}
```

and it adds the swiping for all cells and I want to add it only to the 3rd one on my list (cells are not generated dynamically). Is there a way of doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the `indexPath` of the cell which is given as parameter and return the appropriate response based on that. Furthermore, you could also check the type of your cell using `func cellForRowAtIndexPath(_ indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell?` if you have different cells or so.

Index path is a class. You can get the index of the current row from the indexPath using `indexPath.row`.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    if ((indexPath.row % 3) == 0) {
       return true
    } else {
       return false
    }
 }
```

Comment: but is the `indexPath` an int that I can compare to number 3? or how exactly could I do it in this case?

Comment: You can compare `indexPath.row` to 3

Comment: Ok, so I did: `if (indexPath.row == 2) { var deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(... } else { return nil }` but still it's possible to slide every cell. With that solution in my 3rd cell I see the string `Hello There!` and when I slide the other ones I see the string `Delete`. Is there a way of completely removing the possibility of sliding the other cells then? :)

Comment: Thank you Jelly :)