# TableView cell height while swiping

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a TableView with expandable cells on tap, using this code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let index = indexPath

    if(selectedIndexPath != nil) {
        if(index == selectedIndexPath) {
            return 90
        }
        else {
            return 60
        }
    }
    else {
        return 60
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    switch selectedIndexPath {
    case nil:
        selectedIndexPath = indexPath
    default:
        if selectedIndexPath! == indexPath {
            selectedIndexPath = nil
        }
        else {
            selectedIndexPath = indexPath
        }
    }
    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
}
```

Now, I also want to add swipe gestures for every cell, using code founded [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32004557/swipe-able-table-view-cell-in-ios9-or-swift-guide-at-least).

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
        let share = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Share") { action, index in
            print("share button tapped")
        }
        return [share]
}
```

Everything is good, except the height of the cells while swiping.

1. cells swiped, sometimes, have big height (even they are not
   selected)
2. cells swiped, sometimes, have small height (even they are
   selected).

I think it's maybe because of the last selected cell height.

I tried to fix with `selectedIndexPath = indexPath` in `editActionsForRowAt` but problem still exists.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQCEe.png

**Edit:** I noticied that if `heightForRowAt` return always 60 the problem remains.

Comment: set selectedIndexPath = nil in editActionsForRowAt

Comment: @Prabhat, same problem.

Comment: override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {selectedIndexPath = nil;
    return true
}

Comment: @SaurabhJain, I already had the function, but without `selectedIndexPath = nil;`. I added, without success.

Comment: you can use bool variable in  editActionsForRowAt and check in heightForRowAt method, may be it help.

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
   let index = indexPath

    if(selectedIndexPath != nil) {
        if(index == selectedIndexPath) {
            return 90
        }
        else {
            return 60
        }
    }
    else {
        return 60
    }
}
```

its work for me or u can also check if any tableview cell all constraint proper. or u can use only one any of tableview height method to obtain better result.

Comment: Unfortunately, all cells are now expanded.

Comment: u can only update selecated cell using indexpath then it will be work

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your input is accidentally getting selected/deselected when you enter editing mode for the cells, due to either the initial tap on the cell or some additional gesture made by the user when you try to access the editing actions.

To avoid this, set `tableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = false` in your `viewDidLoad`.

Alternatively, try wrapping your code in `didSelectRowAt` with `if tableView.editing == false`.

Comment: Same result with both recommendations.

Comment: Have you tried to set breakpoints in both `heightForRowAtIndexPath` and `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` to determine what the values are when you being your swipe to edit action?

Answer (score 0):

I solved by initially hiding the content (in my case is one button named `button`) showed after tapping (View > Drawing > check **Hidden**) and in `cellForRowAt` I use:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "CustomCell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! CustomCell
    if(selectedIndexPath != nil) {
        if(indexPath == selectedIndexPath) {
            cell.button.isHidden = false
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```