# How to add image on UITableView delete button?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have an UITableView and I've added edit actions to it. Now I want to add image above the delete buttons label, as:

[image]

This is my code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let blockAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Block") { (rowAction:UITableViewRowAction, indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> Void in
        //TODO: Delete the row at indexPath here
    }
    blockAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

    return [blockAction]
}
```

How can I add image on my `Delete` button?

Comment: @rmaddy but how other developers do that?

Comment: Perhaps they are using a 3rd party custom table view cell class and not using the standard API provided by the `UITableViewDelegate`.

Comment: refer to this questions, you will find your answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20290766/change-the-color-of-default-red-color-delete-button-in-uitableviewcell-when-swip

----------------

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29335104/how-add-custom-image-to-uitableview-cell-swipe-to-delete

if you are on iOS8+

Comment: Only the 2nd link is relevant. I forgot about the idea of using a "pattern image" for the background color. That could work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use special image on background color and use '\n' symbol for let down text

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let blockAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "\nBlock") { (rowAction:UITableViewRowAction, indexPath:IndexPath) -> Void in
        //TODO: Delete the row at indexPath here
    }
    blockAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "delete_background")!)

    return [blockAction]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a swipeable tableviewcell to accomplish this where you can implement custom button for edit actions. There are lot of tutorials on this. Check the below one:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/62435/make-swipeable-table-view-cell-actions-without-going-nuts-scroll-views